# Rails Setting 3.2.14 uses Webrick rails 4.00rc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed rails on windows using railinstaller.

Using a copy of Agile Web development with Rails as my guide to learn with.
So I want to use 3.2.14 as its closer to the version they used in the book.

However after I set that version.

```
C:\work>rails _3.2.14_ --version
Rails 3.2.14
```

and create my new rails env

```
C:\work>rails new demo
...
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

C:\work>cd demo

C:\work\demo>ls -p
Gemfile       README.rdoc  app/  config/    db/   log/     test/  vendor/
Gemfile.lock  Rakefile     bin/  config.ru  lib/  public/  tmp/
```

When I now start a rails server I get version 4.0.0rc of rails running. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
C:\work>cd demo

C:\work\demo>rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0.rc2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-08-15 10:08:39] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-08-15 10:08:39] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-05-15) [i386-mingw32]
[2013-08-15 10:08:39] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1652 port=3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `rails _3.2.14_ new demo` to create a Rails 3.2.14 project.